# My site is taking a very long time to load, what can I do to investigate the issue?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, umbraco

my site is ASP.NET,C#, .net 4, using Umbraco 4, IIS 7.5 it has been working great for months but suddenly its taking ages just to load a single page and mostly not loading at all.

The DB looks fine,

I've restarted the site,

recycled the APP pool,

looked in the logs, it just looks like jibberish

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can investigate further. No I am not asking you to fix my site or tell me why it is not working, I just want to know other methods for investigating the problem so I can get to the bottom of the issue.

IIS LOG:

http://pastebin.com/msjzty7m

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the url ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) to see where the problems might be.

Comment: says: The website specified cannot be reached.

Comment: I'm pinging your URL and even then I'm getting Time-outs. I'd reckon your server at 195.130.201.109 is offline, or the DNS does not resolve to the correct server.

Comment: oh, I can access the server, the files, all the other sites on the server work fine too

Comment: Try pinging another site on the server and see if it resolves to the same IP

Comment: Are you by any chance looking at a cached version? :) Clear your cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Set up the ELMAH error log and take a look if some unhandled expcetions.
2. Set up mini profiler, maybe it is a bottle neck inside a new added script.
3. Use google PageSpeed Insights to analyze your pages.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be it is infact a data issue. Not that it's taking a long time to grab the data but to process it. I've had a few times now where a page is around 138Kb but took over 3 seconds to wait for the page before rendering. Basically this was cause it was running a 3 tier repeater (repeater inside repeater inside repeater) to create the menu system. So even though the site wasn't big it was taking time processing this menu before sending it out.

Suggestions from me would be to comment out anything new that you've added before this date and bring stuff back in slowly till you find the problem part. After that you can look at caching. And if it's a module (.ascx) use [@ Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) and that could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not loading at all... the online tools can not help, you need to investigate whats happens on the server.

The tools for that is the [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from sysinternals to see what is running slow your server, then the [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to see what you loading with out your knowledge and also slow down your system, and the [tcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) to see who is connected to your server.